# IE6 not letting JS set attribute

Tags: css, internet-explorer, class, compatibility

```
document.getElementById("gD" + gDay + gMonth + gYear).setAttribute("class", "gDay gDayHover");
```

This works fine in all modern browsers, unfortunately for me it needs to work in older versions.  I'm using IE8's compatibility mode, and it doesn't seem to cope with this piece of code.

It's getting the element fine, but not changing it's class.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the `className` property. This should work fine in IE6 and above.

```
var elem = document.getElementById("gD" + gDay + gMonth + gYear);
elem.className = "gDay gDayHover";
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but not in other browsers, is it possible to try catch this so that it chooses the correct method?  What is the most efficient way to acheive this as this function is called many times.

Comment: I'd say the most efficient and easiest way to acheive what you want would be to use a Javascript framework such as jQuery. If that's not something you're interested in, have a look at how one of the frameworks solves this specific problem.

Comment: Also Tom, what do you mean by "Other browsers". I tested this quickly in IE6, IE8, Firefox 3.6 and Chrome.

Comment: @Tom In what "other browser" does this not work? `className` is a DOM level 2 attribute and should be supported across the board.

Comment: If I set to className, in Chrome it doesn't respond

Comment: Look at the example jsfiddle link I've provided above Tom. Does this work for you in Chrome? If so, it may just be something minor you're doing that's stopping it.